# Send seekbar's values instead of text string

Tags: android, send, seekbar

I'm developing an app based on the BluetoothChat example where I have the main activity with 2 buttons:

```
1. Find devices
2. Configuration
```

With the first button I search for devices with the same code as in the mentioned example.

With the second button, I enter to another activity where i have 3 seekbars with textviews under each one showing the current seekbar's value.

What I need is to modify BluetoothChat example's code to send an array with this 3 values instead of text.

This is the code of this activity where I'm trying to develop this.

How can I do this?

```
 /*********************
 * 
 * ONCREATE
 * 
 ********************/

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.configuration);

    bar1 = (SeekBar)findViewById(R.id.fastbar);
    bar1.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(this);
    progress1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.out1);

    bar2 = (SeekBar)findViewById(R.id.climbbar);
    bar2.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(this);
    progress2 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.out2);

    bar3 = (SeekBar)findViewById(R.id.platformbar);
    bar3.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(this);
    progress3 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.out3);

    mPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

    /**Initialize the buffer for outgoing messages*/
    GlobalVar.mOutStringBuffer = new StringBuffer("");
}




/*********************
 * 
 * SEEKBAR
 * 
 ********************/

/**Method to get each seekbar's value and save it into a textview*/
@Override
public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar bar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
    switch (bar.getId()) {
        case R.id.fastbar:
            progress1.setText(progress + "%");
            break;
        case R.id.climbbar:
            progress2.setText(progress + "%");
            break;
        case R.id.platformbar:
            progress3.setText(progress + "%");
            break;
    }
}

@Override
public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
}
@Override
public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
    seekBar.setSecondaryProgress(seekBar.getProgress());
}



/*********************
 * 
 * ONRESUME
 * 
 ********************/

/**Load seekbar's values from sharedpreferences*/
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    loadedProgress1 = mPreferences.getInt(Key_PROGRESS_1, 50);
    bar1.setProgress(loadedProgress1);
    loadedProgress2 = mPreferences.getInt(Key_PROGRESS_2, 90);
    bar2.setProgress(loadedProgress2);
    loadedProgress3 = mPreferences.getInt(Key_PROGRESS_3, 70);
    bar3.setProgress(loadedProgress3);
}



/*********************
 * 
 * ONPAUSE
 * 
 ********************/

/**Save seekbar's values on sharedfreferences*/
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();

    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mPreferences.edit();

    savedProgress1 = bar1.getProgress();
    editor.putInt(Key_PROGRESS_1, savedProgress1);
    savedProgress2 = bar2.getProgress();
    editor.putInt(Key_PROGRESS_2, savedProgress2);
    savedProgress3 = bar3.getProgress();
    editor.putInt(Key_PROGRESS_3, savedProgress3);
    editor.commit();
}




/*********************
 * 
 * OPTIONS
 * 
 ********************/

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    /**Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.*/
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_conf, menu);
    return true;
}

/**Options menu where I call the send function*/
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.send:
            sendValues();
            break;
        case R.id.reset:
            resetValues(null);
            break;
    }
    return true; 
}




/*********************
 * 
 * SEND & RESET
 * 
 ********************/

public void sendValues() {

    /**Seekbars values*/
    String message1 = progress1.getText().toString();
    String message2 = progress2.getText().toString();
    String message3 = progress3.getText().toString();

    /**Check that we're actually connected before trying anything*/
    if (GlobalVar.mTransmission.getState() != GlobalVar.STATE_CONNECTED) {
        Toast.makeText(this, R.string.not_connected, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return;
    }

    /**
    *
    *HERE IS WHERE I'M TRYING TO CREATE A FUNCTION TO SEND THE 3 VALUES IN A STRING TYPE MESSAGE
    *THIS CODE IS FROM THE SETUPCHAT() FUNCTION, SO IS WRONG IN THIS CASE        
    */

    /**Get the message bytes and tell the to write*/
    byte[] send = message.getBytes();
    GlobalVar.mTransmission.write(send);

    /**Reset out string buffer to zero*/
    GlobalVar.mOutStringBuffer.setLength(0);
}


public void resetValues() {

    defaultValue1 = 50;
    bar1.setProgress(defaultValue1);
    defaultValue2 = 90;
    bar2.setProgress(defaultValue1);
    defaultValue3 = 70;
    bar3.setProgress(defaultValue1);

}
```

This is the new function created:

```
    public void sendValues() {

    /**Send the seekbars values*/
    String message = progress1.getText().toString()+":"+progress2.getText().toString()+":"+progress3.getText().toString();
    String[] values = message.split(":");
    for (String value : values) { 
        int number = Integer.valueOf(value);
    }

    /**Check that we're actually connected before trying anything*/
    if (GlobalVar.mTransmission.getState() != GlobalVar.STATE_CONNECTED) {
        Toast.makeText(this, R.string.not_connected, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return;
    }

    /**Get the message bytes and tell the Transmission to write*/
    byte[] send = message.getBytes();
    GlobalVar.mTransmission.write(send);

    /**Reset out string buffer to zero*/
    GlobalVar.mOutStringBuffer.setLength(0);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can send the values as a string with a regularExpression ex. `"5:15:33"` and then split it when you receive the string on `":"` Like this.

```
String str = bar1.getText().toString()+":"+bar2.getText().toString()+":"+bar3.getText().toString();
```

Send str String to the reciver and, you can then get the int's out of the String array like this

```
    String[] values = str.split(":");
    for (String value : values) {
        int number = Integer.valueOf(value);
    }
```

Comment: Sorry but I'm new on adroid and I would need a more detailed explanation

Comment: Ok, let supposse that the values that I want to send are in the `bar1`, `bar2` and `bar3` textviews. Where should i introduce these values in your code?

Comment: The previous post is edited adding the code of this part. I have a warning telling that the **number** int local variable is never used.

Comment: Okay the Split part is ment to be on the recivers side. And then the number was just to show you how to get the numbers out of the String array.